# How do you say "ALL the $n$th roots"?

Tags: complex-numbers, radicals

$\sqrt[2]{1}$ is strictly only $1$, despite the equation $x^{2}=1$ having two solutions: $1$ and $-1$. Same with cube roots; $\sqrt[3]{1}$ is strictly just $1$, despite $\left(-\frac{i\sqrt[2]{3}+1}{2}\right)^3$ and $\left(-\frac{i\sqrt[2]{3}-1}{2}\right)^3$ both being $1$ as well. Is there a way to say "ALL the cube roots of 1" or, more broadly, "All the $n$th roots of $x$"?

Comment: If you say "the cube roots of unity", then it is clear that you mean all of them. In mathematical terms, $1,\zeta_n,\zeta_n^2,\ldots ,\zeta_n^{n-1}$ for the $n$-th roots of unity.

Comment: Didn't you just say it? What precisely do you need?

Comment: All n-th roots of 1 are called $\text{n}^{\text{th}}$ roots of unity

Comment: Now that I think about it, {x|x^n=a} is a perfectly reasonable way to say "all the nth roots of a"

Comment: You are missing $x\in \Bbb C$, because you mean the complex roots of unity. One can define this for other fields as well.

Comment: @DietrichBurde That's a good point, it could be confused for only the real $n$th roots.

Comment: "ALL the nth roots" means "the nth roots". And yelling doesn't clarify. Moreover, what is "strictly" supposed to mean? (And consider the sentence meaning when instead not using it or using "not strictly".)  Clarity comes from good phrasing & organization & attending to the meanings of words. And forcing oneself to write clearly instead of sloppily is a good way to promote seeing things clearly.

Comment: Also, you should list them exactly as @DietrichBurde did, and use the same variable. Your readers will have seen the same notation hundreds of times, and immediately recognize it and know what you're referring to.

Comment: OP: On the off chance you're still tracking this, I agree with @philipxy's comment regarding "strictly." I would say, rather, that $\sqrt{1} = 1$ *by convention*, rather than "strictly." And in fact, that is the main place where such a convention is necessary. For the cube root, $\sqrt[3]{1} = 1$ is the only real root, so if the context is the reals, that's the only choice anyway, convention or no.

Comment: Incidentally, I think I can guess why you inserted it, but the $2$ on the radical of your numerators $i\sqrt[2]{3} \pm 1$ is a bit confusing because they look almost like the exponent of $i^2$. I think you don't need them there, if you're still looking to improve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In informal usage, you can say "the $n$th roots of unity"; that is generally understood to mean all *complex* $n$th roots of $1$. If you want to emphasize this—say, because you've previously been restricting yourself to real values—you can say "the $n$ complex $n$th roots of unity."

Symbolically, you can write

$$
\{ z \in \mathbb{C} \mid z^n = 1 \}
$$

If these don't suffice, you may want to edit your question to clarify what requirements you have for the wording.

Answer (score 0):

The set of all $r$ such that $r^n=x$ can be written as $\{r \in\mathbb{C}: r^n = x\}$ and is equivalent to the set of all the $n$th roots of $x$.

Comment: It *is* the set, don't say it is equivalent to the set. You seem to be trying to account for the informality of the asker's characterization, so you might want to say, "{...}, which holds[/contains/comprises] the nth roots of x". Also when you are not quoting the asker "all" is redundant.